# Alternative for .then() after request()

Tags: node.js, request

I'm new to NodeJS. I have an asynchronous function

```
request({url: 'url',json: true}, function (error, response, body) {});
```

I want to call a function only after this function is invoked. I can't call a .then() here. What are the other alternatives for this situation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
    request({
        url: "",
        method: "",
        headers: {},
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if(!error)
            resolve(body);
    })
}).then(value => {
    // process value here
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Just pass it as your callback function:

```
function callback (err, res, body) {
   // Do what needs to be done here. 
}    
request({ url: 'url', json: true, someParam: true }, callback);
```

At the beginning of your callback function, check if `err` exists and if so, handle the error.

This [article](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) might help you.

You can only call `then` if your asynchronous function returns a Promise. But before you get into Promises, you should know the basics about Node.js.

Comment: I already have a callback function. I need to call this new function after the callback function.

Comment: Then you have to call it inside of your callback function

Comment: I have to write 4 file inside this callback function. That's an asynchronous process as well. Now, I want to call that function only after I'm done with writing all those 4 files. That will not be possible to put inside callback, will it?

Comment: It is possible but you'll get into [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/). So you might want to use promises anyway. Promise libraries like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) can transform your request method so that it returns a promise. You can also look at [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async).